# Use sed to replace the last space in each line with a comma, then remove all spaces

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a two-column, space delimited .txt file, but the first column has spaces (which are errors). I need to convert it to a csv, but I can't just replace all the spaces with commas.

Example input:

```
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-2  3-diol_1    2-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614] 1
```

Desired output:

```
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-23-diol_12-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614],1
```

How can I use `sed` (or anything else) to replace the last space in a row with a comma, then remove all remaining spaces? Would that effectively create a CSV file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
sed -r 's/(.*) /\1,/; s/ //g'
```

The first substitution, being greedy, will cover all but the last space in the group, replacing the last with a `,`. The second will then eliminate the rest.

Comment: It's not working  correctly for me :/ (replaces a space between the line except the last one).

Comment: @Thor Now it's correct ;)

Comment: @Thor thanks! My keyboard's been a PITA since I spilt coffee on it. :(

Comment: @muru rule of IT, Software Engineering, and Engineering #1:  Thou shall not spill your coffee, but consume it completely, cup by cup

Comment: Easier solution: `sed 's/.* /&,/;s/ //g'`. When all spaces get removed anyhow, it makes no difference to append the comma after the last space, so you don't need that `\1` stuff and extended RE.

Answer (score 3):

This would do the job:

```
sed -r "s/\s([0-9]+$)/,\1/" filename.txt | tr -d ' '
```

or:

```
sed -r "s/\s([0-9]+$)/,\1/; s/\s//g" filename.txt
```

Input example:

```
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-2 3-diol_1    2-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614] 1
```

Output:

```
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-23-diol_12-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614],1
```

Comment: I like the example with `tr` since it's explicit, so more readable to new users, but second `sed` is quote good as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a geeky way - with a sed loop.

1. if the pattern contains only a single space, replace it with a comma
2. (otherwise) replace the first space with nothing and goto 1

which we can write in GNU sed as

```
sed -e :1 -e '/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/ s/ /,/' -e 's/ //; t1'
```

Testing:

```
$ echo 'gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-2  3-diol_1    2-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614] 1' | 
  sed -e :1 -e '/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/ s/ /,/' -e 's/ //; t1'
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-23-diol_12-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614],1
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl

```
$ perl -ne 's/\s//g;s/^(.*)([[:digit:]])$/\1,\2/;print' input.txt                                                                                    
gi|118592783|ref|ZP_01550172.1|_biphenyl-23-diol_12-dioxygenase_[Stappia_aggregata_IAM_12614],1
```

or shorter:

```
perl -pe 's/\s//g;s/^(.*)([[:digit:]])$/\1,\2/' input.txt
```

Effectivelly this is the opposite of muru's approach: we get rid of all spaces first, then group everything before last item (group `\1`) and last item (group `\2`, two which happens to be digit). We replace the line with group `\1` and `\2` being separated by comma.

Note that `([[:digit:]])` can be changed into `(.)` to reference any character,in case that's necessary (i.e., if we expect last char to be of any type), or we can use `([[:graph:]])` to deal with only printable chars